# Can someone identify this specific Dungeons and Dragons product I picked up at a thrift store?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

[image]

It has little to no information other than what you see. I'm pretty sure it's 1E, but I can't figure out much of anything about it. I was looking at wikipedia's list of DnD products and their release dates, and I can't narrow it down to a singular item. It comes with both the books a vague Amazon seller referenced in an identical but poorly described entry for the product.

I'm not interesting in playing it, I only really play 3e/3.5e/Pathfinder. I just wanted it for the novelty, I picked it up for twenty bucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got that at a **thrift store?!**  And for $20?!?! That bro, is the original red box.  That is worth its weight in gold.  You're looking at one of the earliest rules-lite versions of AD&D and it dates back to 1983!  Treasure it bro.

Quote from Wikipedia on it

> 1983 revision
>
> In 1983, the Basic Set was revised again, this time by Frank Mentzer, and redubbed Dungeons & Dragons Set 1: Basic Rules. The set included a sixty-four page Players Manual, a forty-eight page Dungeon Masters Rulebook, six dice, and in sets in which the dice were not painted, a crayon. The 1983 revision was packaged in a distinctive red box, and featured cover art by Larry Elmore. Between 1983 and 1985, the system was revised and expanded by Mentzer as a series of five boxed sets, including the Basic Rules (red cover), Expert Rules (blue), Companion Rules (teal, supporting levels fifteen through twenty-five), Master Rules (black, supporting levels twenty-six through thirty-six), and Immortal Rules (gold, supporting Immortals, characters who had transcended levels). Instead of an adventure module, the Basic Set rulebooks included a solo adventure and an introductory scenario to be run by the Dungeon Master.
>
> The 10th Anniversary Dungeons & Dragons Collector's Set boxed set, published by TSR in 1984, included the rulebooks from the Basic, Expert, and Companion sets; modules AC2, AC3, B1, B2, and M1 Blizzard Pass; Player Character Record Sheets; and dice. This set was limited to a thousand copies, and was sold by mail and at GenCon 17.
>
> An Australian version of the Basic Set was printed by Jedko Games in 1987.

Comment: It's not worth its weight in gold, it's not the original, and it's not a rules-lite version of AD&D. The [Set 1 book](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/44081/dungeons-dragons-set-1-basic-rules) is worth [about $11 mint](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/rulebooks.html), it's the the third or fourth edition after the original, and it's from a line parallel to Advanced D&D called "Basic D&D". It *is* a treasure, but for play and sentimental value, not collector value. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the 1983 Edition of the basic rules box set.  The product info is included in this sales listing for one of the rulebooks which was a part of the set [here](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/116619/DD-Basic-Set--DMs-Rulebook-BECMI-ed-Basic)

Comment: It looks like the link does not send us to the set itself anymore. I suppose these are for sale and get removed once sold...